# Is it possible to define a different page layout for every chapter title page for example?

Tags: geometry, afterpage, layout

I attempted to produce a book document that has the following specifications:

1. A narrow content at the first page of each chapter, but the width of the chapter title is as wide as `\textwidth`.
2. A sided box that contains – for example objectives or partial toc.
3. The remaining pages have normal layouts as shown below

[image]

Unfortunately, I failed to find my codes to be used as mwe. But my main idea was to use `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` commands combined with `\afterpage` command. But I failed. The question is:
Is it even possible to do such a thing? simple answers are sufficient, so there is no need for a complete example. (The question may be updated as soon as finding a mwe)

Comment: You could do it with minipages and \fbox.  The only problem is if you intend for text to flow across a change in width.  Of course we are talking custom \chapter.

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer, in general it is difficult.

You are asking for the main text to be set to two different widths; firstly on the chapter page and secondly on subsequent pages. LaTeX typesets a paragraph at a time to a constant width; if a paragraph starts on a chapter page and ends on the next page its typeset width will be the same on both pages.

You can manually ensure that no paragraph extends from the chapter page to the next by inserting the macro `\parnopar` (provided by the `memoir` class) just after the last word on the chapter page.

```
\newcommand{\parnopar}{\parfillskip=0pt\par\parskip=0pt\noindent}
...
...end of last line on chapter page\parnopar start of first line on next page...
```

The `\parnopar` puts an "invisible" paragraph break into the text, though sometimes it might be desirable to leave a space between the last word and `\parnopar`.

Answer (score 1):

Flowframe package might be able to handle this, especially the textflow; or a set of minipages/multicols. A pure Tikz solution should be possible. `wrapfig` and related packages (usually dealing with figures) and `parshape` command offer possibilities. Perhaps even `epigraph`package. Or even just a `tabular`? Or lua code?

It is a matter of joining two things, text flow and chapter formatting. Which belongs to which?

Here I present a proof of concept as a standalone page, as a first step:

[image: chapter heading as a page]

Using existing packages, in `article` class, a height-filling `tcolorbox` stretching to the bottom of the page in the second column of a `paracol`, with free-form text in the first column, its column height matching the colorbox; with `paracol` natively dealing with the `section` title which in turn is formatted as a chapter-like entity by `titlesec`. "Flowing" the text to the following page (or not) will be done manually. The location is a natural home for a chapter summary.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand\sectiontitlename{Chapter}
\titleformat{\section}
{\hrule\vspace{2ex}\normalfont\scshape\color{blue!60}\centering}%format
{\sectiontitlename\ \thesection}%label
{1em}%sep
{\ \\\normalfont\Large\bfseries}%before; space for toc for NL
[\vspace{6pt}\hrule\vspace{1.7ex}]%after


\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{2.55em}
\dottedcontents{section}[3.8em]{}{2.3em}{1pc}

\tcbset{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,nobeforeafter}

\usepackage{paracol}
\backgroundcolor{c[0]}[rgb]{0.8,1,0.6}
\columnratio{0.7}

\newcommand\ptext{Qwerty
Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty Qwerty }


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\begin{paracol}{2}[\section{Introduction}]
\ptext \lipsum[5]
\switchcolumn
\begin{tcolorbox}[height fill=true,text fill,nobeforeafter]
Qwerty \vfill
\end{tcolorbox}
\flushpage
\end{paracol}
\lipsum[7-9]

\newpage
\begin{paracol}{2}[\section{History}]
\ptext \lipsum[5]
\switchcolumn
\begin{tcolorbox}[height fill=true,text fill,nobeforeafter]
Qwerty \vfill
\end{tcolorbox}
\flushpage
\end{paracol}

\lipsum[7-9]

\newpage
\begin{paracol}{2}[\section{Devlopments}]
\ptext \lipsum[5]
\switchcolumn
\begin{tcolorbox}[height fill=true,text fill,nobeforeafter]
Qwerty \vfill
\end{tcolorbox}
\flushpage
\end{paracol}
\lipsum[7-9]

\end{document}
```

A lot of work has gone into these packages. I am very impressed. There must be someway to return the favour.